How to make predictions on new data using only one feature if we trained the model on many features?
I am building a model which predicts the percentage of completing the loan timely,and i have trained the model on various features or indepenedent variables,such as loanAmount, loan_start_date, loan_end_date, amountPaid and i also carried out some feature extraction and its  performing well. But now i want to only use one feature and that is loanAmount when making predictions or on new data,How can i achieve that?

The best solution is to train a new model with only one input feature.

This begs the question: since you intended to use only one feature, why did you train your model with the rest of them in the first place?

It seems there's a misunderstanding of how features work in machine learning models. When you train a model on multiple features, it learns a relationship using all of those features together. The model's coefficients or weights are optimized considering the influence of each feature on the target variable.
If you now want to make predictions using only one feature (e.g., loanAmount), you can't directly use the existing model trained on multiple features. This is because the trained model expects the same structure and number of features as during training.
You really only have two options here:

Train a New Model with Only loanAmount: You need to retrain the model using just the loanAmount feature. This way, the model will learn the relationship between loanAmount and the target variable, ignoring the other features.

Use the Existing Model but Provide Default Values: If you must use the existing model, you have to provide all the features it was trained on, even if they aren't meaningful. For example, you can set loan_start_date, loan_end_date, and amountPaid to some default or average values, but this is not recommended as the model’s predictions might not be reliable.


